# Confused about geom_uzip and how its used

Tags: freebsd

I have an geom_uzip image and what I'm confused about is the following. The first few lines of the image file are as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
#V2.0 Format
m=geom_uzip
(kldstat -m $m 2>&-||kldload $m)>&-&&mount_cd9660 /dev/`mdconfig -af $0`.uzip $1
exit $?
```

But when I try to execute them manually they simply don't work on the mount part as the memory drive with extension .uzip doesn't exist. For example executing mdconfig -af root.img generates /dev/md0, but the the top of the image loads the file_name.uzip. How is that happening ?

Also, I've been looking around for ways of testing  the geom_uzip images and can't really find anything online. Does anyone know of any?

Comment: After creating memory disk, what does `geom uzip list` show? Are you certain that the image was created using `mkuzip`?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I do see the code at the top of the file. Wouldn't that be an indication that it is mkuzip? geom uzip list returns empty. I had it return a list once, but I don't know what I did to get it like that.